# My .gitignore file is not working

Tags: git, github

I've been trying everything I can think of and I've read all the StackOverflow posts about this issues, yet I can't seem to fix it.

The issue here is that I 
 1. created a repo (test) , which git is tracking
 2. Inside my test folder, I have a .gitignore file
 3. I've opened my .gitignore file on sublime which looks like this:

[image]

I've tried with and without adding and commiting the .gitignore file on terminal, which doesn't matter both way's since it doesn't work.

When I type git status, I still see the files that need to be commited an the ones that are unstaged.

See my terminal:
[image]

What am I missing here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Replace

```
* .css
```

by

```
*.css
```

(and same for the other ones)

[Relevant documentation](http://git-scm.com/docs/gitignore)

Comment: Unbelievable I didn't see that one myself!! 
Thank you it works fine now.

Comment: What about this file:-  .DS_Store - 
 It's still showing up to be staged.

Comment: Just use `.DS_Store`.

Comment: Works fine here, with `*.DS_Store`and with `.DS_Store`. But the problem is that your .DS_Store has already been commited before, and is thus marked as modified, and not untracked. You'll need to use `git rm` to remove it, then commit.

Comment: Never mind I got this one. 
Of course, once a file is tracked in your repository, it will continue to be tracked even if it matches an entry in an applicable .gitignore file.

You have to manually remove the .DS_Store files that were added to your repository. You can use git rm --cached .DS_Store. Once removed, git should ignore it.

Comment: This will however apply it only for this repo. 
How about if I wanted the .DS_Store not to be staged for any of my repo's?
I'm assuming this would be setting it in my config globally. 
Where do I put this file after creating it so it is applied to all future repo's?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/81120/discussion-between-brain-and-jb-nizet).

Comment: I checked the link you shared and a few things are still unclear to me. 
I just ran this in my terminal: git config --global core.excludesfile ~/.gitignore_global 
And it's probably set up now. 

However I also noticed there is a gist which contains some good rules. Now if I want to add those rules to my .gitignore file (the one that is global), where can I find it?

Comment: You need to create the file `~/.gitignore_global` if it doesn't exist yet. `~` is your home directory. Execute `cd` to go home. Then create a file named `.gitignore_global` containing your rules in that directory.

Comment: Works like charm!  I wasn't aware that ~  was my homedirectory. 
Thanks